# Predicting classification of outcome at different points in time

Tags: time-series, classification, predictive-models, missing-data

I have a real world problem where I need to predict an event happening. The event is a binary category (T/F). We learn more and more information about what the outcome of an event will be as time goes on and certain actions happen. In the beginning we have very bare bones information but you may be able to make a model based on that. At the end you can almost certainly predict what’s going to happen because of new information. I can think of a few parallel examples:

1. a tennis match - when they step on the court you have a prediction of who will win. By the first, second set that may change dramatically. By the last point you’re pretty sure who wins.
2. a legal case where you would predict the judge’s ruling at various points on the case. Toward the end it may be leaning very much one way.

I want to be able to predict at various points. The points are not on an exactly consistent time interval. Sometimes things unfold quicker or slower, but there are basically patterns of “actions”, and certain things tend to happen before others (if they occur at all).  In fact these actions can be one hot encoded and they do have time stamps, as does the final outcome classification. I’m not really interested in predicting the next event. I’m interested in predicting the final outcome at any given time with the different levels of info available to me.

I don’t know what kind of model is best for this. It doesn’t really seem like a time series. I’ve tried simple classification like decision tree/ random forest but it doesn’t account for me wanting to predict at various points with different amounts of info. What kind of model would you suggest??